# Xfce, evolution, need same font for all, working area and email head, body

Tags: fonts, xfce, evolution

**Os**

```
Linux local 5.0.0-21-lowlatency #22-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Jul 2 14:10:55 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Need**

In Xfce, evolution mail, I need same font for all.

**Problem**

As you can see below on pictures, font is maybe the same, but word spacing is different. In subject is OK, but in content of message is different, quite ugly, for example `To` text.

[image: example-1]

[image: example-2]

In mail preferences, I have this, which is the same font as my system, font with nice word spacing.

[image: settings]

What is wrong? Or should I setup font of message elsewhere?

Comment: You haven't told us the release of Xubuntu.  XFCE has been moving from GTK+2 to GTK+3, and Evolution is the GNOME MUA, and I wonder if this is a factor (and don't know where you are, in order to compare with my own).

Comment: @guiverc Updated in question.

Comment: I only see a kernel version, not what I wanted (Xubuntu release from which I can work out XFCE version). You could be on 19.04, but also 18.04 LTS using HWE (which has a much older XFCE)

Comment: @guiverc DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 19.04", but seems that I solved this issue. Where can I write solution, to my question with "update", or create new answer? Thanks.

Comment: I've never asked a question on this platform, but on my screen the answers section is below the question with a large 'Post an Answer' button that opens it.

Comment: @guiverc Yes, I know, but what is better, answer the question, or update my question?

Comment: If you solved it, post an answer on this question.  If you now have another question, start a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

Solved, it works for me.

You just copy all content of `~/.local/share/fonts` to `/usr/share/fonts`.

Then in evolution, go to `Edit > Preferences > Mail Preferences > Message Display`, and change the font you like.

BR.